# How to set and update global variable's value from HTML5 Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, html, variables, event-handling, server-sent-events

I want to set, update global variable's value that using HTML5 Server Sent Events.

This is my server code

```
$chart = [
    ['name' => 'User A', 'data' => range(1, 3)],
    ['name' => 'User B', 'data' => range(1, 3)],
    ['name' => 'User C', 'data' => range(1, 3)]
];

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$stream  = 'event: chart' . "\n";
$stream .= 'data: ' . json_encode($chart) . "\n\n";

print $stream;
flush();
```

This is my client code.

```
var source, chart_data;
if (!!window.EventSource) {
    source = new EventSource('/stream/chart-data');
    source.addEventListener('chart', function(event) {
        // It's work.
        console.log(event.data);

        // It's not work.
        chart_data = event.data;
    }, false);
}

// It's not work.
console.log(chart_data);
```

I try to set new value to `chart_data` but it's always `undefined`.
How can I set new value to global variable?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your code is asynchronous. When `console.log(chart_data)` is being called outside of your event listener it has not been given a value yet.

When you log the value of chart_data in the event listener you will see that the value has been set. You can also try logging `chart_data` in your JavaScript console and see the value being set if you wait until after the asynchronous call has been called.

To make this more clear, you can do add a timestamp to the `console.log` and you will see that the `console.log` called inside of the event listener has a smaller value than the one in the event listener because it's called at a later time.

Comment: Thanks Brian de Heus. Can you give me some advice to add new value to global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions to access the global variable inside the chart event:

```
var source, chart_data;
if (!!window.EventSource) {
  source = new EventSource('/stream/chart-data');
  source.addEventListener('chart', (event) => {
    console.log(event.data);

    this.chart_data = event.data; //access using this variable
   }, false);
}
```